# 多重配列の各配列の指定した値が最も初めにあるのは何番目にあるか判定

Tags: python3

下記の多重配列があります。

```
li = [['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '1'], ['0', '0', '1', '1']]
```

"1"の値が最初あるのは何番目にあるか判定したいのですが、分かる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？
"1"がない場合は0とします。

目的の出力結果

```
0, 0, 3, 2
```

Comment: 先頭にあった場合(インデックスが0番目)と存在しなかった場合の区別が付かなくても良いのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
出来れば区別出来れば幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

```py
[i.index('1') if '1' in i else 0 for i in li]
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
解決し、今後の参考になります。